# How to enable bidirectional mirroring for a github repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-actions, cicd

I have a repo on github, how to enable bidirectional mirroring for free, either on something like gitlab ce or some other solution or via cron or webhooks, whatever works.

so we have an organization on github but one member cant access github because of the country of residence. I want for this member to be able to contribute without having to shift the entire organization away from github. I'm looking for either a free solution or a self hosted one.

I don't mind using alternative to gitlab, I just want something that works.

VPN is not an option because if the employee forgets to connect before accessing the repo, the organization gets banned.